# The purpose of SynchronizationContext.CreateCopy

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, task-parallel-library

The following is a typical implementation of [`SynchronizationContext.CreateCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.createcopy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public class CustomSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
   // ...

   public override SynchronizationContext CreateCopy()
   {
      return this;
   }
}
```

The MSDN docs are scarce about this method. My questions are:

1. Under what circumstances does it get called by the Framework?
2. When to implement the actual copy logic, rather than just returning a reference to the
   source instance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It gets called by ExecutionContext.Capture().  A rather important method, it sets up the Thread.ExecutionContext property.  And is used to ensure that a thread that is started will use the same synchronization provider as the original thread that started the worker thread.  It makes sure that a call marshaled by Post or Send goes back to the correct thread.

Whether you need a copy or not depends on what you expect to happen when the original synchronization provider ends its lifetime.  There certainly isn't any need for a copy of SynchronizationContext, its Post/Send methods don't actually do any useful marshaling at all, Post just runs the target on a threadpool thread, Send just executes the target immediately.  So just returning *this* is good enough.

It does matter on a real provider, like WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext(marshals with Control.Begin/Invoke) or DispatcherSynchronizationContext (marshals with Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke).  When the UI thread of a Winforms or WPF app ends and a worker thread is still executing and making invoke calls then you want a get a good diagnostic.  Which requires keeping a reference on the original Control or Dispatcher so it can throw a decent exception, like InvalidOperationException or ObjectDisposedException. The copy adds the reference.